# Prove these two ODEs are equal given a base for their solution set

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've been going at this question in my homework for a while now and I can't think of a way to prove it. Any hints or nudges in the right direction would be appreciated!

Let $B:=\{y_{1},y_{2}\}$ be a base for the solution set of the linear ODEs $$y''(x)+a_{1}(x)y'(x)+a_{0}(x)y(x)=0$$
$$y''(x)+b_{1}(x)y'(x)+b_{0}(x)y(x)=0$$
where $a_{1}(x), b_{1}(x), a_{0}(x), b_{0}(x)$ are continuous functions in some real interval $[a,b]$. Prove $a_{1}(x)=b_{1}(x)$ and $a_{0}(x)=b_{0}(x)$

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ form a linearly independent system of solutions to both the equations

$y''(x) + a_1(x) y'(x) + a_0(x) y(x) = 0, \tag 1$

and

$y''(x) + b_1(x) y'(x) + b_0(x) y(x) = 0, \tag 2$

we obtain, by setting $y(x) = y_1(x)$ in each of (1) and (2),

$y_1''(x) + a_1(x) y_1'(x) + a_0(x) y_1(x) = 0, \tag 3$

$y_1''(x) + b_1(x) y_1'(x) + b_0(x) y_1(x) = 0; \tag 4$

we subtract (4) from (3):

$(a_1(x) - b_1(x))y_1'(x) + (a_0(x) - b_0(x))y_1(x) = 0; \tag 5$

we likewise have,

$(a_1(x) - b_1(x))y_2'(x) + (a_0(x) - b_0(x))y_2(x) = 0; \tag 6$

in matrix-vector form (5)-(6) become

$\begin{bmatrix} y_1(x) & y_1'(x) \\ y_2(x) & y_2'(x) \end{bmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a_0(x) - b_0(x) \\ a_1(x) - b_1(x) \end{pmatrix} = 0; \tag 7$

by virtue of the linear independence of the functions $y_1(x)$, $y_2(x)$,
the matrix is non-singular for all $x \in [a, b]$, whence

$a_0(x) - b_0(x) = 0, \tag 8$

$a_1(x) - b_1(x) = 0, \tag 9$

and hence

$a_0(x) = b_0(x), \tag{10}$

and

$a_1(x) = b_1(x), \tag{11}$

$OE\Delta$.

Comment: Thank you so much. My first approach was to try using the linear independence of B but I couldn't make the argument stick. Thanks for the clear answer!

Comment: @gr8astard:  my pleasue my friend.  The key is that if $B$ is a linearly independent set of *solutions*, then the vectors $(y_i(x), y_i'(x))$, $i = 1, 2$, are linearly independent for all $x$, a standard result.  Cheers!